# Is it safe to give my APK and API files to my customers?

Tags: android, ios, apk, ipa, mobile-application

I created ios and android apps, so now i have to deliver to my customer in IPA and APK file formate.

I want to know, is it possible for them to extract the ipa and apk files and get into my main codes ?

Friends please educate me. Thanks guys.

Comment: Yes.  Of course it is-  if you give anyone any executable they can reverse engineer it.  If you couldn't read the instructions, neither could the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For android,

Consider enabling your ProGuard

ProGuard obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names which make the code base, smaller and more efficient. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer.

to enable proguard

set minifyEnabled to true and add rules you need on proguard-rules.pro file.

Useful reference
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

For iOS

I don't think there is an easy way to reverse engineer an ipa file

Answer (score 0):

Seem like they can get your code from your `APK` file (Android) and `IPA` file (iOS). (I'm not trying it, just for consult)

For `android`, the answer can be found here

[Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

For `iOS`

https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source